# Laravel automated view generation from models

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-artisan

In Laravel, I can create models and controllers automatically from the command line using

> artisan

However, There is no command to generate views automatically based on the the model for CRUD operations. Wonder if there is a tool that would make this out of the box. I imagine this:

```
php artisan make:view model
```

and then I have all my views ready. I tried to search online but could not find a proper tool: LarvelCodeGenerator, and others...

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Laravel View Generator](https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-view-generator).

Comment: Looks good but makes empty views. not based in a model with basic implementation to show table contents or to create a form to add data to the table. I just feel this should be automated! :)

Comment: I think the decision was made to not bloat the default offerings of Laravel. May do some good creating a package, I don't mind helping out on GitHub if you create one.